# sed escape rule for {$TENANTCODE$}

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

Need a small help while executing this command :

```
grep -rnl '{$TENANTCODE$}' $LCL_PTH/InitLoad/Company/ | xargs -i  sed -i -r  "s#/{\$TENANTCODE$/}\#$CLNAME#ig" *
```

Am getting the error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command
```

Any suggestions/idea on where I went wrong.

Comment: are you trying to replace literal `{$TENANTCODE$}` with `$CLNAME`? if so, try `sed 's#{$TENANTCODE$}#$CLNAME#ig'`.. note the use of single quotes.. and also there shouldn't be `*` at end of sed command

Comment: That `\#` is most probably wrong.

Comment: also, not sure of the option `-i` used with `xargs`... no point in using `-n` option with `-l` in grep... probably better to use `grep -rlZ` and then `xargs -0`

Comment: `'s#{\$TENANTCODE\$}#$CLNAME#ig'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't actually terminate your `s` command:

```
sed -i -r  "s#/{\$TENANTCODE$/}\#$CLNAME#ig"
             ^                  ^       ^
             |                  |       delimiter, start replacement text
          opening           literal #,
          delimiter        part of regular expression
```

I assume you don't want the backslash before the second `#`.